# Using different Standard C++ library headers with Intel compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, icc

I am trying to have the Intel C++ compiler use different standard library C++ headers than the compiler's default ones. The headers that the compiler would use per default unfortunately do not define a particular type trait/function that I need.

```
$ icpc --version
icpc (ICC) 16.0.2 20160204
Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

The headers I'd like to use are located in

```
ls /opt/crtdc/gcc/4.8.5-4/include/c++/4.8.5/:

algorithm  cfenv      condition_variable  cstring    ext               iostream  numeric           sstream       tuple
array      cfloat     csetjmp             ctgmath    fenv.h            istream   ostream           stack         typeindex
atomic     chrono     csignal             ctime      forward_list      iterator  parallel          stdexcept     typeinfo
backward   cinttypes  cstdalign           cwchar     fstream           limits    profile           streambuf     type_traits
bits       ciso646    cstdarg             cwctype    functional        list      queue             string        unordered_map
bitset     climits    cstdbool            cxxabi.h   future            locale    random            system_error  unordered_set
cassert    clocale    cstddef             debug      initializer_list  map       ratio             tgmath.h      utility
ccomplex   cmath      cstdint             decimal    iomanip           memory    regex             thread        valarray
cctype     complex    cstdio              deque      ios               mutex     scoped_allocator  tr1           vector
cerrno     complex.h  cstdlib             exception  iosfwd            new       set               tr2           x86_64-redhat-linux
```

But whatever I try, I either get

```
icpc -std=c++11 -o test test.cc -Qlocation,cxxinc,/opt/crtdc/gcc/4.8.5-4/include/c++/4.8.5/

error: namespace "std" has no member "declval"
```

(here I think the compiler uses it's default header location) or

```
icpc -std=c++11 -o test test.cc -nostdinc++ -Qlocation,cxxinc,/opt/crtdc/gcc/4.8.5-4/include/c++/4.8.5/

test.cc(2): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "utility"
  #include <utility>      // std::declval
```

(here it doesn't use any C++ headers at all, because the -nostdinc++ flag disables it all together, I guess)

The test.cc program just exercises the C++11 standard library feature that I'd need:

```
// declval example
#include <utility>      // std::declval
#include <iostream>     // std::cout

struct A {              // abstract class
  virtual int value() = 0;
};

class B : public A {    // class with specific constructor
  int val_;
public:
  B(int i,int j):val_(i*j){
    std::cout << "ctor\n";
  }
  int value() {return val_;}
};

int main() {
  decltype(std::declval<A>().value()) a;  // int a
  decltype(std::declval<B>().value()) b;  // int b
  decltype(B(0,0).value()) c;   // same as above (known constructor)
  a = b = B(10,2).value();
  std::cout << a << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to be sure to have this properly motivated. The default C++11 headers on this system do not support the std::declval. That's why I try to use the GCC ones' which do support it.

```
$ icpc -std=c++11 -o test test.cc
opa.cc(19): error: namespace "std" has no member "declval"
    decltype(std::declval<A>().value()) a;  // int a
                  ^
```

Comment: I doubt it is a fruitful excercise. I am afaraid days when standard library could be used outside of it's compiler are gone - there are too many compiler intrinisic in there nowadays. But what type trait do you need?

Answer (score 6):

Found it!

```
icpc -std=c++11 -o tes test.cc -cxxlib=/opt/crtdc/gcc/4.8.5-4/
```

The Intel compiler expects the executable bin/gcc to be present in that path and queries the location for the C++ headers using this executable.

Comment: It's really not straight forward to find this information from the man page. So it's good to have this on SO

Comment: Sadly, this option was deprecated in Intel 17 (`icpc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-cxxlib=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0'`), or at least this is what I see on Mac.

Comment: @JeffHammond just want to add that this flag doesn't seem to be available on Mac, but on a Linux system icpc -help shows `-cxxlib[=dir]
          link using C++ run-time libraries provided with gcc dir is an
          optional top-level location for the gcc binaries and libraries`

Answer (score -1):

Compilers and their standard libraries are pretty tightly bound. I doubt you'll get anywhere with this endevour.

Use a different compiler/std lib or poke Intel to fix their implementation, then upgrade.

Comment: Intel compilers are an exception. They are designed to be compatible with GCC toolchain on Linux (and MS toolchain on Windows), including stdc++.

Comment: ...and LLVM compiler toolchain on Mac.